# Starting SDK Manager gives Java.NullPointerException on my mac

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sdk

I have my Android SDK located in Documents, I have all my Dev files there only. 
 I installed Java Runtime.
`java -version` returns 
 `java version "1.8.0_291"` 
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)`
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)`

Starting `android` in `android-sdk-macosx/tools` gives me the NullPointer Exception.

Any idea why is this happening? I already installed all the android packages by executing `tools/android update sdk --no-ui`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but it seems that you installed Java Runtime Environment (JRE), while Android SDK needs Java Development Kit (JDK). JDK contains JRE, but JRE is not enough for Android SDK.
If you want to install JDK 1.8 from Oracle, here is the link:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html
(there is a MacOS version in the page)